# Can I bypass the switchboard and the main control box of a kitchen range hood and connect it directly to power supply?

Tags: kitchens, appliances, electric-motor

I have a typical range hood in my kitchen that is not working. I suspect that either the switchboard and/or the main control box are faulty. I don't have access to a professional repair workshop where I live. Here are the components inside the hood (I apologize, I don't know the jargon of the electrical components):

- The main Switchboard with 4 soft touch buttons for 4 different fan speed
- The main Control box with the following connections:
  - A wire from the switchboard on one side.
  - the main power plug coming from the wall socket.
  - Two DC plugs going into the LED lights.
  - one five-pins plug that goes into the exhaust fan motor.
  - There is also a white tube-shaped of what I assume is a capacitor with wires
  coming from and going into the five-pin plug.

Here is my question. Can I bypass the switchboard and the main control box with all the pins and plugs and just connect the fan directly to the main power cord coming from the wall socket? I don't care about having different fan speeds. I'm satisfied with just manually plugging it into the wall socket every time I want to use the hood.

Comment: if you provide make & model, it would help

Comment: Most certainly you can bypass the switch board, if there are no other electrical components.

The fan will run at only one speed, probably at maximum. Read the label on the motor, what does it says. Without capacitor it might not start.